# Getting the Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I just setup my old pc to run SQL Server and VisualSVN. I have a laptop and another pc that i need to work on a website and that is why i setup subversion and sql server on a seperate pc. I have set up VisualSVN and ToirtoiseSVN but im getting SQL Server Problems below is how im connecting to the DB:

```
Imports API.Database
Public Class DatabaseHelper

Private _SqlServer As SQLServer

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property SqlServer() As SQLServer
    Get
        If Me._SqlServer Is Nothing Then
            Me._SqlServer = New API.Database.SQLServer("192.168.1.3", "sa", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxx")
        End If
        Return Me._SqlServer
    End Get
End Property

End Class



Public Sub New(ByVal server As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal database As String)
        If server = "" Then
            server = "(local)"
            //server = "localhost"
        End If
        If username = "" Then
            username = "sa"
        End If



        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={3};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={1};Password={2};", server, username, password, database)
        //''''''Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={3};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, username, password, database)


        //''Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("chatterconnectionstring").ConnectionString
        Try
            Me._SQLConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Me._SQLConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If True Then
                Throw ex
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I have read a few articles and found that becuase i am running the SQL Server on another location and my web project on an IIS in another location this is why i am getting permission problems but how do i fix this?

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express R2 and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Is this error from IIS or SQL?

Comment: @JonC i am sure that the error is from SQL

Comment: Can you connect remotely using the SSMS with the same credentials?

Comment: Just as a test can you try hard-coding your connectionstring and see if that connects? As long as SQL allows remote connections and you have a correct connection string I don't see what other issues you would have. Could you send the link to the article you read on the issue?

Comment: @JonC the article i read was here http://forums.asp.net/t/1012271.aspx/1 and the link to the reply is here http://forums.asp.net/post/2010310.aspx

Comment: When does the exception get thrown?

Comment: So this line Me._SQLConnection.Open() is where the exception is thrown? Do you have impersonation turned on? It looks like the web app is passing the logged on users creds to the sql connection somehow.

Comment: @Richard, at the try catch condition after Me._SQLConnection.Open()

Comment: @JonC i have set <identity impersonate="true"/> in the web config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Integrated Security=false in your connection string

Comment: @redoc01 Anytime and glad I could help. Just for completeness of this thread. Integrated Security ignores the username/password in the connection string and uses the apps credentials and since impersonation was on it used the anonymous credentials